# CMake third-party library installation

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm new in programming. And for my study project I need to install a third-party library for using with CMake ([GitHub project](https://github.com/cpp-io2d/P0267_RefImpl/blob/master/BUILDING.md)).

I use Arch OS on my PC. Usually I build all non-repository packages in: *~/aur*. CMake version is 3.17.

Then I try to build a library according to the instructions:

```
...
cmake --config Debug "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" ..
```

it makes me an error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
PNG_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /home/wizki/aur/P0267_RefImpl/P0267_RefImpl/Tests

-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

If I ignore this error and build this library using:

```
cmake --build .
```

The building is succesful, but durin my project building I have an error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findio2d.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "io2d", but
  CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "io2d" with any of
  the following names:

    io2dConfig.cmake
    io2d-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "io2d" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"io2d_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "io2d"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

After a web search I've tried this solution: [Daniweb](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/438160/png-include-directory-cmake). 
libpng and zlib packages are installed; FindPNG.cmake exists in */usr/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/*.
But my *$CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH* and *$CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH* are empty:

```
[wizki@evix Debug]$ echo $CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH

[wizki@evix Debug]$ echo $CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I've tried to search in FindPNG.cmake for paths, but no result. From [CMake wiki](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/find_package.html) I suppose that one of the library path is */usr/lib*. I've tried to build a library inside, but I have a same issue.

What can I try next?

Comment: "libpng and zlib packages are installed" - You have installed `-dev` packages too, haven't you? Check that you have `/usr/include/png.h` and `/usr/include/zlib.h` files.

Comment: This is a good first question. We tend to encourage technical writing, so I've made a small edit, but good work - lots of effort and research here.

Comment: There aren't `-dev` version for Arch, but there are `-git` versions. I think that this is not the same things. I've checked `/usr/include` for mentioned header files. The both exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are studying for the C++ Nanodegree Project on Udacity. I was stuck on the same issue and I found out that during the installation of IO2D after you execute the following command in the terminal

```
cmake --build .
```

execute the following command

```
sudo make install
```

this will copy the necessary files at places where Cmake can find them.

Therefore, the complete process looks like this

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/cpp-io2d/P0267_RefImpl
cd P0267_RefImpl
mkdir Debug
cd Debug
cmake --config Debug "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" ..
cmake --build .
sudo make install
```

I found the solution here - https://github.com/udacity/CppND-Route-Planning-Project/issues/1#issuecomment-569472612

PS: As you are new to programming I would like to share a tip that many times other people also have the same issue and it is easier to find a solution in the "Issues" tab of a GitHub repo.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I remember to see this solution, but I've ignored it, because for me `install` command refers to Ubuntu's `apt` (my fallacy). Happy to take into account you tip about "Issue" importance.

Comment: this solution works for linux. I'm blocked by the same issue but on macOs system