# CMake io2d error missing CAIRO_INCLUDE_DIRS CAIRO_LIBRARIES

Tags: cmake, core-graphics, cairo

I'm trying to follow the steps on this link:https://github.com/cpp-io2d/P0267_RefImpl/blob/master/BUILDING.md 
to install io2d.
However I get an error message after I write the cmake ..:

```
C:\Users\walid\Desktop\Udacity_Nanodegree\RoutePlanningProject\build>cmake ..
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.18362.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findio2d.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "io2d", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "io2d" with any of
  the following names:

    io2dConfig.cmake
    io2d-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "io2d" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "io2d_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "io2d"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/walid/Desktop/Udacity_Nanodegree/RoutePlanningProject/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Therefore I found this suggestion On StackOverflow:
[CMake third-party library installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61025954/cmake-third-party-library-installation/62243634#62243634)

**But I get a new error message here it is:**

```
cmake --config Debug "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" ..
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.18362.
Default IO2D backend was not specified, choosing automatically...
Found Windows, using CAIRO_WIN32.
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
CMake Error at C:/CMake/cmake-3.17.3-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
  Could NOT find Cairo (missing: CAIRO_INCLUDE_DIRS CAIRO_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/CMake/cmake-3.17.3-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:445 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindCairo.cmake:102 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  P0267_RefImpl/P0267_RefImpl/cairo/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
```

PS: I'm using Windows, I have CMake,Make,g++ and gcc installed.

Here is a screenshot demonstrating that I have Cairo already installed:
[image]

Comment: When format multi-line logs, do NOT use *blockquote* formatting: This formatting doesn't preserve newlines, which makes harder to read the log. Instead, use **code** formatting. (This recommendation is just for the future. In your current post I have already fixed formatting of the logs.)

Comment: Well, the error is about missing Cairo. Do you have it installed? Its installation  is noted in the guide you follow.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes I have installed it as mentioned in the guide.

Comment: You execute the command `cmake --config Debug "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" ..` which doesn't correspond to the build manual you refer to: it lacks for `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` setting (without this setting vcpkg is not used), it lacks for `VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET` (it seems you have cairo installed only for x64, but I am unsure whether you build for x86 or x64).

Comment: @Tsyvarev the command described in the manual gives me the error message: CMake Error: The source directory "c:/tools/io2d.sln" does not exist. I have cloned the repo from github, but somehow doesn't contain the io2d.sln file, where normally should this file be found?

Comment: Please, show (add to the question post) the **exact command** you have run when get this error.

Comment: I have added the command I used in the question post and the error log that displays- @Tsyvarev

Comment: `io2d.sln` is NOT a part of `cmake` command invocation. This is a **separate command**, which should be issued **after** `cmake`.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev, I run the new command, however I got a new error message (I edited the question post to show the new error message)

Comment: And what about  `Win64` part in the generator specification? Yes, it doesn't work for `Visual Studio 16 2019` generator (as opposed to one `Visual Studio 15 2017` described in the guide). But it has a replacement: additional option `-A x64`. See documentation for the generator you use: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Visual%20Studio%2016%202019.html.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have used the generator with the option -A x64, however I get a new error message, I have edited the question post to show it

Comment: The error message contains and an advice: `Either remove the CMakeCache.txt file and CMakeFiles directory or choose a different binary directory.`. Have you tried to follow it?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried deleteing the CMakeFiles directory and the CMakeCache.txt and it worked fine, what is the next step, to write the command io2d.sln? And after that? Because I'm trying to use the command CMake to build this project https://github.com/udacity/CppND-Route-Planning-Project And when I write cmake to build it I get an error saying complaining about io2d, I have updated the question with the new error message

Comment: `io2d.sln` is a Visual Studio project. You may open it in the Visual Studio and **install** it, so it could be used by other projects with `find_package`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok so I opened the project, to install it I should clique Build Solution?